# getting error while running fancyRpart command

Tags: rattle

Please help me
I am not able plot using fancyRpart command though I have installed rattle and other dependency like RGtk2,rpart.plot& rpart.

I am using  R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) on windows 10 getting following error
set.seed(123456)

> modelFit<-train(classe ~.,method="rpart", data=TrainSet)
>
> fancyrpartPlot(modelFit)

Error: the object passed to prp is not an rpart object
In addition: Warning message:
In max(model$frame$yval) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Please add some example data and code. It might be useful to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Please do provide complete reproducible exapmles otherwise we have to guess.

I think you are using caret::train(). This returns an object of class "train", not the actual final model but it does encapsulate the model and much more meta data: see ?caret::train.

Try:

```
fancyRpartPlot(modelFit$finalModel)
```

A reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
library(rattle)

modelFit<-train(Species ~., method="rpart", data=iris)
fancyRpartPlot(modelFit$finalModel)
```